# Best database for mobile phone development

Tags: iphone, database, android, windows-mobile, mobile-phones

I am writing an application that initially will be developed as web (probably Silverlight) and Android application. I found on Android [website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) that SQLite is supported, but I plan to release the same app for Windows Mobile, Palm Web OS and iPhone as well.

Could you please advice me on which database would be the best to work with for all platforms?

EDIT:
Maybe I should add that I would want all applications (mobile/desktop) to connect to a main server when internet connection is detected and synchronize all data that's changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sqlite should be available on all those platforms (certainly on android an iPhones).

However, it probably doesn't matter. You're not going to be calling directly into the Sqlite API, you're going to be using the "data" API on the phone.

That, and each platform has it's own preferred programming language, so even if you were using the Sqlite api directly, you wouldn't have the ability to cross-compile.

If you have data to import for your app, I think I'd try to find a platform-neutral format (like a text file) that you could use to import into the various api's.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is supported by all platforms mentioned. As far as know thats what our teams that working on those platform are using. So i'd say stick with SQLite

Answer (score 0):

SQLite runs on all the platforms you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Way to late to the party here, but i will add my two cents anyway. Couchbase Lite database is new and gaining a lot of momentum. It meets all the above said requirement you can check it out here
http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/